# Uploading files in RESTful way?

Tags: java, python, file, rest, file-upload

I'm designing a RESTful API that should handle binary file uploads.
Should this be done the same way as html form upload or is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the Amazon api for an idea. It uses a PUT query and then through sendREST it sends the content. 
[Uploading files to Amazon S3 with REST API](http://www.anyexample.com/programming/php/uploading_files_to_amazon_s3_with_rest_api.xml)

Answer (score 1):

A good way is to upload the binary information using streams. You could have a look at the JeCARS client project. To be exact the [JC_RESTComm.java](http://kenai.com/svn/jecars~jecars-repository/jecars/jecars_client/src/org/jecars/client/JC_RESTComm.java) class performs the upload.